# Show that there exists a $3 × 3$ invertible matrix $M$ with entries in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ such that $M^7 = I_3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Show that there exists a $3 × 3$ invertible matrix $M$ (which is not the identity matrix) with entries in the field $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ such that
$M^7 = $Identity matrix.

All I could do was use hit and try method. I was checking different matrices which might satisfy this condition. Of course, it's a bad approach.

Comment: If you know group theory, you can instead show that $7$ divides the order of $\operatorname{GL}_3(\Bbb F_2)$.

Comment: fantastic! thanks

Comment: @RolfHoyer How does it proves that the matrix M must be invertible?

Comment: @No-One Any matrix satisfying $M^7=I$ is necessarily invertible, since $M^6$ is an inverse of $M$.

Answer (score 3):

We have the factorization $X^7-1 = (X+1)(X^3+X+1)(X^3+X^2+1)$ over $\mathbb{Z}/2
\mathbb{Z}$.  So such matrices are exactly those with characteristic polynomial $X^3+X+1$ or $X^3+X^2+1$—the companion matrix of either polynomial, for example.

Comment: :What can be the matric satisfying this  $X^3+X^2+1=0$?

Comment: @PKStyles $A=\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&0&-1\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&-1\\0&0&1&-1\end{matrix}\right)$.  Look up companion matrices.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how enlightening it is to literally just have an example of such a matrix to "understanding" the structure of $GL_3(\Bbb F_2)$, but for what it's worth,

$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&1\\0&1&1\\1&1&0\end{matrix}\right)$$

is such a matrix, found by enumerating all the matrices (there are only $512$ so it's not so bad).

Comment: how did you come up with this matrix? Can you please explain your reasoning? and how did you check that it satisfies the given condition?Did you multiply it seven times?

Comment: @BasantSharma I used a computer to multiply it seven times, yes. I came up with this matrix via the obvious method - try them all until one works. (In fact there are $49$ such matrices satisfying $A^7=I$, including the identity matrix, out of the $512$ total $3\times 3$ matrices and $168$ invertible matrices.) You will probably get more mileage out of the "well-reasoned" answer, but sometimes examples can help just by giving you a viewpoint from which to visualize the problem.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro:I also calculated this $A^7$ with the help of online calculator but i come up with the following result-$$
    \begin{matrix}
    5 & 14& 14 \\
    14 & 33 & 28 \\
    14 & 28 & 19 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$Here is the link for the calculator http://matrix.reshish.com/powCalculation.php

Comment: @PKStyles This is a matrix in $\Bbb F_2$, meaning that all odd numbers are the same as $1$ and even numbers are $0$. Note that the matrix you wrote has the property that the diagonal numbers are odd and the off-diagonal elements are even. So that is actually just $I$, as a matrix over $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro:Apologies!,i totally forgot about the field